# How to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin with js

Tags: python, python-requests

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=RELIANCE' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is my code

```
  const zonofne = async function handleSubmit() {
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  };
  await axios
    .get("https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=RELIANCE", {
      headers,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
zonofne();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beautifulsoup` HTML parser:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

params = {
    'q': 'what is the capital of india',
    'hl': 'en'
}

url = 'https://www.google.com/search'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

capital = soup.select_one('[data-attrid="kc:/location/country:capital"]')
print(capital.text)
```

Prints:

```
New Delhi
```

Comment: can i get using class name from the web page

Comment: @santosh Of course, you can. But classnames on google changes often I think, so it's better idea to find other methods how to select the required elements.

Comment: what method can we use

Comment: @santosh You can use `soup.find()` or `soup.select_one()` Here is `bs4` documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: could you please help me by using class name to get the text # new delhi #

Comment: @santosh You can do `capital = soup.select_one('.Z0LcW.XcVN5d')`

Comment: how did you get [data-attrid="kc:/location/country:capital"] this